PrizmDoc Server and PrizmDoc Application Server Docker Version Fail to Display Jpeg
I trailing a Docker Version of PrizmDoc Server and Application Service in Linux, Version 14.0, and I note they have made some differences. The main difference is the depreciation of their secret key.
My question is this, I already have a compiled application that sends the key. When I try this the jpeg is not rendered. I can't see any errors and I tried adding the key to PAS yaml file.
Is there away of getting it to either accept or ignore the key? The application is air gapped. So, there is no access to the Internet.
